# How to properly use python import when building an exportable library

Tags: python

Say I have a project structure as such:

```
/project_name
  setup.cfg
  pyproject.toml
  /src
    /package1
      __init__.py
    /package2
      __init__.py
      module.py
```

I want to import and use `module.py` in `package1/__init__.py` and I can do so with the two following imports (relative or absolute):

1. `from ..package2 import module`
2. `import src.package2.module`

This works ok for developing the library and testing it, but my issue arises when the end user installs and uses the package downstream. Inside my setup.cfg file I have:

```
...
[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find:
...
[options.packages.find]
where = src
```

I've been using `py -m build` to build the .tar.gz and -py3-none-any.whl files and uploading them to a private repository. Users can then install it using:
pip install --extra-index-url http://mysite/private/repo project_name --trusted-host mysite

The install goes ok, but when when they go to try and use package1 with `import package1` that is where things get messy as they get one of these errors:

1. "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

   - This happens when I use `from ..package2 import module` as described above
2. "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'"

   - This happens when I use `import src.package2.module` as described above

**Update**

I found that if I restructure my project as such I get it working for the end user:

```
/project_name
  setup.cfg
  pyproject.toml
  /src
    /project_name
      __init__.py
      /package1
        __init__.py
      /package2
        __init__.py
        module.py
```

The end user can use the modules using `from project_name import package1` which I was hoping to keep it down to just `import package1` but whatever that is fine. What I really have a problem with is that in package1 I HAVE to use a relative import:

`from ..package2 import module`

The reason this bothers me is because I've read in several places that it is better to use absolute imports as the end user can modify the path and screw things up, but if I do it this way:

`import src.project_name.package2.module`

It breaks the end user running the code because they don't see `src`!!! So I guess the heart of my question is: how does python determine what the root package is? Why do I have to use `src` in the import statement (which DOESN'T have a `__init__.py`) instead of just `project_name.package2.module`. I've looked all over and can't seem to answer this. Very confused.

Comment: You developed `package1` as if it would be part of the larger package `src`, but then install `package1` and `package2` separately, not as part of `src`.

Comment: Similar to what @chepner said – it's not clear what your overall package is called. However, if you do a single `pip install <package-name>`, then you should be using that in place of `src` in your `import src...` statements. I would also steer entirely clear of relative imports for this.

Comment: In my setup.cfg I have a name specified as `[metadata] name = my_package` so when users install it they use `pip install my_package`. If I don't have this import dependency in package1 then the packages themselves are easily used using `import package1` or `import package1`. Many of the tutorials out there suggest using src as the container for everything even though it isn't use explicitly by the end user.

Answer (score 0):

The way you setup your build/install, everything would be installed following the tree hierarchy below `src` (not including `src`). And you can do:

```
import project_name
import project_name.package1
```

Note that in this setup you cannot do `import package1`. It seems like **in your development environment you have modified PYTHONPATH so you can do `import package1`, and this is what causes your issues**. In this case python treats `package1` as the top-level package, and you cannot do a relative import that goes above the top-level. It seems you have also set your development environment so you can do `import src.project_name.package1`, which is inconsistent with the actual install location.

You cannot do relative imports between two separate packages. They need to be within a larger package, like your `project_name`, as you found out. **If you want relative imports, you definitely need this top-level package**.

Bottom-line, if in your development environment you set your PYTHONPATH to search in the `src` directory, you can do `import project_name.package1` and either a relative import

```
from ..package2 import module
```

or absolute import (note I do not include `src`)

```
import project_name.package2.module
```